# How to place an funktion in an echo?

Tags: php, echo

I've searched for this for a while (also SO), but I just don't get it. I want to place an echo `<?php echo get_tag_link($tag_id); ?>` within an echo:

```
<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    $count=0;
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $count++;
            if (1 == $count) {
                echo '<span class="tags"><a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag_id); ?>">';
                echo $tag->name . ' ';
                echo '</a></span>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

But clearly this is wrong..

Comment: you're already in PHP `<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag_id); ?>">` and error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have helped you find that syntax error. So, why an "echo in an echo"?!

Comment: Don't nest echoes inside echoes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already working within a PHP block so you don't need the `<?php ?>`

Similarly you're already echoing a string so the `echo` is also not needed.

What you're looking for is [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Like this:

```
echo '<span class="tags"><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag_id) . '">';
```

Comment: That was what i was trying to do, thanks, man! I knew that the secound PHP was wrong and that i hat to work with the dots somehow.. I'm too noobish, sorry ^^

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the row to:

```
echo '<span class="tags"><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag_id) . '">';
```